# auto detect facebook session in FB connect sites

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

a simple problem is that i want when user logged in to Facebook so user automatically
 logged in to my sites.i have FBconnect implemented in my site .no refresh the page..

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {

         //what to do here???
          //i dont want to use setTimeout() in this function to check it again & again
    }
   });
```

any idea how to do this???

Comment: This code is wrong. You need to use: if (response.authResponse) {

Comment: @Abby but in my app i wrote this its not working...thats why i did so..

Comment: Maybe you are initialising the FB object without oauth: true? Can't really help without seeing more code or a link to the live example

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need...

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: but if user already visted my site than user need to refresh i achieve the same thing but when user refresh the page.how about without refreshing...

Comment: Why would you need to refresh? You can put JS in the event subscribe response function to change whatever you want on the page to show you are logged in, or ajax data back to the server?